# Set inline dblclick() listener to element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an table, which is contructed in js and then appended to div on the page.
Each line has an inline event listener onclick()

```
 var table = '<table>';

 for (var i =0; i< 10; i++) {
   table += '<tr onclick="myfunction()"><td></td></tr>'
 }

 table += '</table>'

$('#myDiv').html(table);
```

**How can I use doulbe click event instead of single click in this construction?**

EDIT: 
I don't use delegation in this case because I have lot's of arguments (uniq for each row) which also constructed inline on each row. Table refreshes about 50 times a second, so it much easier to once construct inline function with all arguments, then setting noumerous listeners after table was appended to DOM.
I've tried both ways and inline in my case works much faster and is much cleaner to inderstand what should happen onclick.

Comment: Why don't you bind event using relevant javascript/jQuery method? Why not delegating this event? And regarding your question, why not using google?

Comment: `Table refreshes about 50 times a second` That's for sure really too much. Anyway, using delegation would avoid many many duplicate handlers and make your code more optimized. To pass specific data depending which row is double clicked, you should just set data-* attribute and use it in delegated handler

Comment: Then I will have to read data property of the row after it's clicked. It will take at least 6 msc which is too much.

And I don't get dublicated listeners, since table fully overwritten every time.

Comment: I guess you are making some kind of real time trading tracker. Anyway your approach is wrong IMHO but that's up to you. And by duplicate handler, i meant each row will have prop ondblclick set for same handler instead of one handler for all the rows

Comment: You are right, it's trading orderbook. Actually, I might not have enought time even to read data property of the row, beacuse all table is already updated. I do have troubles even with onclick event, since when onmusedown fired, table refreshes and I don't get onmouseup and hence no onclick event...

But anyway I don't see a way to construct dblclick event based on mousedown. Timeout? Too heavy.

Comment: Just for test purpose, using ondblclick attribute, i'm still not able to fire callback, too fast reupdate: http://jsfiddle.net/3RtSg/  Even using the simple click  :(  The same using delegation anyway... :(

Comment: yep. returned to simple mousedown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `onclick` to `ondblclick`.

But, using inline js is a bad idea.

Since you are using [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), you can use event delegations.

Answer (score 1):

Since one of the tags in your question is jQuery, I would resort to use jQuery for this task and would not hook up your event handlers directly in your DOM element.

```
$('#generatedTable').on('dblclick', 'tr', function() {
    alert('tr is clicked');
});
```

Where generatedTable is the id of your table.

Using **on** will allow to respond to all double click of the generated trs

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WdNU3/2/)

Comment: OP should use from his example: `$('#myDiv').on('dblclick', 'tr', myFunction);`  http://jsfiddle.net/KSnRw/  Anyway +1 because you provide delegation example, what OP should use

Comment: Now imagine that each row consists of at four columns, value of each one is an argument for the function. And table refreshes with all values more then 50 times a second.
Constructiong row inline I don't have to read arguments (or keep them anywhere except DOM), I already have them inline.

Comment: if your table refreshes 50 times a second, you might have a different problem with the overall design of your app.... and yet not seeing any problems with "on" handler.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute you're looking for is called [`ondblclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.ondblclick), however do allow me to point out that it's bad to use event attributes like this, to quote MDN:

> This way should be avoided. This makes the markup bigger and less readable. Concerns of content/structure and behavior are not well-separated, making a bug harder to find.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event#HTML_attribute